# how to install to install jre-7u7-linux-x64.tar.gz

Tags: 12.04, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a .tar.gz  (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)
>   [How can I install Sun/Oracle’s proprietary Java 6/7 JRE or JDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)

i have just download a file jre-7u7-linux-x64.tar.gz  and i am new to ubuntu so i don't know how to install it. i only can install a software from software center.
 can someone help me to install it on ubuntu 12.04 os and tell me the steps so that another time i don't need to ask question to install a file.

Comment: Here's [howto install Oracle java](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-ubuntu-12-04.html).

Comment: sudo tar -xzf archive.tar.gz. This is used to unzip the archive.